# Pass React State Down As Prop, Without Defined Children Components

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

We're working on an admin portal. We've got a user account page, where the user will be able to edit their personal info and eventually stuff like security, privacy, notifications, etc.

Note: We're using classes and not functions. Let's skip the questions on "why" or trying to "sell me this pen" on using functions over classes.

Note: Also, for reference, we're using [https://mui.com](https://www.stackoverflow.com/). Just in case you need to know.

1. We've got a page template for all portal pages, called `<PortalTemplate/>`.
2. On the `PortalTemplate`, we are using a cookie, to execute a `getUser()` function that returns user details. This is captured in `this.state.account`.
3. The user's account page is injected as `this.props.children`.

```js
// PORTAL TEMPLATE (basic):
export interface PageProps {
  children: any;
  pageTitle: string;
}

export interface PageState {
  account: AccountDTO;
  anchorEl: HTMLElement | null;
  isLoginActive: boolean;
  isMenuOpen: boolean;
}

export default class PortalTemplate extends React.Component<PageProps, PageState> {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This portal template is used for ALL portal pages, as sort of like a wrapper that contains the global menu stuff. We're trying to determine how to actually leverage the state variables, but also sending this down to children component pages so they can use the same details to render dynamic data.

```js
// ACCOUNT PAGE (basic):
export default class AccountPage extends React.Component<PageProps> {
  constructor(props: PageProps) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <PortalTemplate pageTitle='Account'>
      { page content here }
      </PortalTemplate>
  )};
}
```

Our problem is that we're having trouble sending the `this.state.account` data down from `PortalTemplate` to `AccountPage` so that the user's account page can use these details to render the data, but also have a form where they can edit their details.

React Ref:
https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components#step-3-add-state-to-the-common-parent

We tried using this reference, but are finding it hard to follow. Since our `PageTemplate` component uses `{ this.props.children }` to allow components to be used "under" it, we're not able to figure out where `this.state.account` is supposed to go in order to be utilized by child pages/components.

We've also tried to clone the child, like other posts have depicted, but was unsuccessful.

```js
{React.cloneElement(this.props.children)}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your problem, but if it's to ensure all children can access values from a potentially distant parent (which it sounds like it might me), this is exactly what [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) was designed for.

Comment: @RobinZigmond, 
That looks very useful. I'll give it a go and see what happens.

Comment: @RobinZigmond, pretty sure I'm confused on this. But...

This looks like it won't work "as is". I created the context in the `PageTemplate`, setup the provider to send data up, and tried to use it in the child. 

I'm definitely lost in the sauce on this. 

Ref:
https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context#step-2-use-the-context

Comment: I don't know what you're doing wrong till I see your code. But at a guess, you've linked to the newer docs which only talk about function components and use the `useContext` hook - you can't use Hooks in classes, so if you insist on sticking with classes you need a `YourContext.Consumer` component instead, as explained in the older docs to which I linked above.